# Rails 7.0.4 and data confirm for link_to doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

My last chance is some last living developer in RoR

Nothing in the darkest corners of the internet works for:

```
<%= link_to 'some-link', '#', data: { confirm:'Are You Sure?') %>;
```

it generate this:

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" href="#">some link</a>
```

but there is no confirm dialog box.

I try everything - **turbo_confirm**, try to add controller with class for stimulus ... and still nothing.

Right now I remove turbo-rails, stimulus etc. - but still nothing.

Comment: no, everything works but after remove whole "turbo"  Devise errors start working

Comment: have you read this: https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/guide-v7-0-3-1-link-to-destroy-turbo-method-delete-doesnt-works-ubuntu-22-04/81326/8

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> `data-turbo-confirm` presents a confirm dialog with the given value. Can
> be used on `form` elements or **links with `data-turbo-method`**.
>
> *https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/attributes*

#### Examples that work

```js
<%= link_to "GET turbo link", "/",
  data: {
    turbo_method: :get,
    turbo_confirm: "Sure?"
  }
%>

<%= link_to "POST turbo link", "/",
  data: {
    turbo_method: :post,
    turbo_confirm: "Sure?"
  }
%>

<%= button_to "Button", "/",
  data: { turbo_confirm: "Sure?" }
%>

<%= form_with url: "/",
  data: { turbo_confirm: "Sure?" } do |f| %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

#### Doesn't work

```js
<%= link_to "GET link", "/",
  data: { turbo_confirm: "Sure?" }
%>
```

Fix by adding `turbo_method: :get`.

---

[@hirowatari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245849/hirowatari) edit:

```js
<%= link_to "GET external link", "http://example.com",
  data: {
    turbo_method: :get,
    turbo_confirm: "Sure?"
  }
%>
```

---

External links or links with extensions (other than `.html` or `.php`) will be ignored by *Turbo*. I think this is one of the reasons `data-turbo-confirm` and similar *Rails UJS* features were not initially implemented in *Turbo*. You'll be better off implementing your own `data-confirm` feature if you're migrating from *Rails UJS*, it is very simple, you won't have to change attributes to `data-turbo-confirm`, and it will just work on any click. See example below.

#### Really doesn't work

```js
<%= link_to "UJS link", "/",
  data: { confirm: "Sure?" }
%>
```

But easy to fix:

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

// this is now my preferred way of dealing with confirmation dialog
// it is just much simpler than Turbo way
document.addEventListener("click", event => {
  const element = event.target.closest("[data-confirm]")

  if (element && !confirm(element.dataset.confirm)) {
    event.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

---

#### data-disable-with

**Update** Use `data-turbo-submits-with` to handle this.

This one is a bit more involved, but it's all the same pattern, listen for event, check for data attribute, if else, do something.

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

// on form submit
// set `value` if `input`
// set `innerHTML` if `button`
document.addEventListener("turbo:submit-start", event => {
  const element = event.detail.formSubmission.submitter
  if (element.hasAttribute("data-disable-with")) {
    // element.disabled = true // this is done by turbo by default
    if (element instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
      element.value = element.dataset.disableWith
    } else {
      element.innerHTML = element.dataset.disableWith
    }
  }
})
```

```rb
<%= form_with url: "/" do |f| %>
  # <button>
  <%= f.button "Submit", data: { disable_with: "..." } %>
  # <input>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", data: { disable_with: "..." } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: and what fix is for data: { disable_with: 'loading...' } ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't like magic links with confirmation dialogues or some special HTTP verbs

I think links must be just links

And if you want some special features — use forms instead

```
<%= button_to 'Some text', some_path, method: :get, form: { data: { turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' } } %>
```

(need add data-attribute [to form](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/4e828875b3c833ad4d978964a6a6f8a629c5d72a/app/assets/javascripts/turbo.js#L634-L647) containing this button)

Comment: Unless you've got delete functionality that's inside a form (which you can't work around)